# can I draw a 2nd degree 2 dimensional surface trough 3x3 points, like I can draw a 2nd degree polynomial through any 3 points

Tags: polynomials

A Nth degree polynomial f(x) fitting N+1 points, say at regular distances like x = 1,2,3,4,5,... can be used conveniently to interpolate for values of x in between the given ones. I have a set of function values f(x,y) given at regular distances like 1,1 1,2 1,3 2,1 2,2 2,3 3,1 3,2 3,3 (actually a 3x3 grid).The question is : Can the values for f(x,y) be interpolated in the z plane by a convenient polynomial in x and y, like one can do in one so easily in one dimension? And if so, how?

I looked myself at functions like aX^2+bX+cY^2+dY+eXY+f,but the fact that we have 9 equations and only 6 unknowns tells me this is not the way.

I thank you all for reading this and possible answers.

Comment: May be, you could use a bilinear interpolation corresponding to $z=a+bx+cy+dxy$ selecting four points. Otherwise, least square fit (multi-linear regression) with your complete model. But, for nine data points, the first will be better. Have a look at ;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might prove useful when it comes to writing questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do: You can find a second degree polynomial in $x$ per row of three points. Then for each degree, you have a different coefficient at three different $y$-values, hence can describe that coefficient by a degree 2 polynomial in $y$. Of course, this would give you a polynomial of total degree $4$ because $x^2y^2$ can occur ...

Comment: A simpler version of this occurs one degree down: $2$ points determine a line, but $2\times2$ points overdetermine a plane; they can only be bilinearly interpolated through, and that surface is a (ruled) quadric.